# How can I create scheduled tasks via Powershell 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed Powershell 4.0 on my OS that is **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

I wanted to create ScheduledTasks by using [Scheduled Tasks Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816.aspx) but it seems they are available only for Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8.1.

**QUESTION**:
What is the shortest way to create scheduled tasks via Powershell 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TaskScheduler module released as part of the [PowerShell Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack). Here is a sample of what you can do with that module:

```
New-task | 
    Add-TaskTrigger -DayOfWeek Monday, Wednesday, Friday -WeeksInterval 2 -At "3:00 PM" |
    Add-TaskAction -Script { 
        Get-Process | Out-GridView 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 100
    } |
    Register-ScheduledTask TestTask

New-task | 
    Add-TaskTrigger -In (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30) |
    Add-TaskAction -Script { 
        Get-Process | Out-GridView 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 100
    } |
    Register-ScheduledTask TestTask
```